# Instruments showing false leak?

Tags: cocoa, memory-leaks

I am not sure why Instruments is showing the following code as leaking 128 bytes on the UILabel initWithFrame line:

```
self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = self.editButtonItem; 
UILabel *tmp = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(25, 100, 275, 100)];
self.emptyMsg = tmp;
[tmp release];
```

Note that in this classes is releasing the emptyMsg property in the following:

```
-(void) dealloc {
     [self.emptyMsg release];
     [self.pathToUsersFriendsFile release];
     [super dealloc];
}
```

At one point I wasn't using the accessor method to set emptyMsg so I expected that change to the make this leak go away.  Alas, it is still showing up.  Can some one point me to another  cause?

Declaration of variable:

```
@interface FriendListViewController : UITableViewController <AddFriendDelegate> {
    NSString *pathToUsersFriendsFile;
    UILabel *emptyMsg;
}
@property(retain) UILabel *emptyMsg;
@end
```

Comment: This probably isn't your issue, but you should never use dot syntax on self in a dealloc method.

Comment: Please post property declaration for emptyMsg

Comment: @rich how about assigning nil to properties in dealloc?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's nothing wrong with the way you've done it. (Although I would take Rich's advice and *not* use the dot syntax in the `dealloc` method; release the instance variables instead.) Instruments shouldn't be confused by it, but Instruments is not perfect. If it is insisting that's a memory leak, it's a false positive.

Comment: Is there really nothing wrong in that way? I'm a novice at Objective-C, so I'm not sure of this, but when he issues [self.emptyMsg release], doesn't the dot syntax call the setter method such that retain count increases by one? The effect of that statement would then be increasing the retain count by one and decreasing it on one line, wouldn't it?

Comment: No. This would be equivalent to writing [[self emptyMsg] release]. This would call the getter, not the setter.