# NSData memory leak...pointing to NSConcreteData!

Tags: iphone, memory-leaks, nsdata

I am having a memory leak, and can't figure it out.  Basically, what I am doing here is pulling in images to a Mutable Dictionary and returning the dictionary.

```
- (NSMutableDictionary *)loadImageDataGroup:(NSUInteger)index {

int lim = 5;
int sta = 0;
if (index > lim) {
    sta = index-lim;
}
int fin = (((lim*2)+1)+sta);
if (fin > [self imageCount]) {
    sta = ([self imageCount]-((lim*2)-1));
    fin = [self imageCount];
}

BOOL firstTime = NO;
if ([imagesLoaded count] == 0) {
    firstTime = YES;
}

NSMutableDictionary *tempDict = [[[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init] autorelease];

for (int i = sta; i < fin; i++) {

    NSString *imageName = [self imageNameAtIndex:i];

    if ([imagesLoaded valueForKey:imageName] == nil) {

        // This is the Memory Leak...at least that is where Leaks is pointing me.
        NSData *imageData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:imageName]];
        [tempDict setObject:imageData forKey:imageName];

    } else {
        [tempDict setObject:[imagesLoaded valueForKey:imageName] forKey:imageName];
    }

}

return tempDict;
```

}

The leak is in the NSData = *imageData spot, and when I pull it up in leaks, it points to NSConcreteData.

Comment: If you see the NSData being leaked, it doesn't necessarily mean the leak is caused by that line. It could be that the entire dictionary is being leaked, or that somebody somewhere else retains that NSData and doesn't release it. I can't see anything immediately wrong with the code in terms of memory.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking at your code, I'm not seeing anything obviously wrong.  Be aware that Instruments can produce false positives.

See the following:

[Instruments showing false leak?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1539983/instruments-showing-false-leak)